# CoreMotion-DeviceMotion not available on iPad 3

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, gyroscope, core-motion

I have this strange problem. In my app I'm asking the device, if DeviceMotion is available:

```
if (coreMotionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable) {

    coreMotionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0;
    [coreMotionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 / 60.0 target:self selector:@selector(didUpdateCoreMotion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"NO DEVICE MOTION" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

but it's always false... 
What am I doing wrong? I'm doing this on my iPad 3 and I already played around with CMMotionManager in the past and with it's .deviceMotion.attitude.roll, pitch and yaw and everything was just fine. But now I just always get alert o.O

Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong? Thx very much for any help :)

**Finally restarting my Mac helped, after restart it all just worked! :) Thanks Kay for sticking around and help :)**

Comment: What do you mean? It's not possible to run more than 1 instance of an app through Xcode, is it? Anyway, killing the app doesn't help :(

Comment: 2 instances of [CMMotionManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html): _Important: An app should create only a single instance of the CMMotionManager_

Comment: In my app only 2 ViewControllers work with "this Core" data, one with LocationManager and the other one with MotionManager. I suppose these 2 do not interfiere with each other. Back to your comment, no, I create CMMotion manager od setup (init) and set it to nil in viewDidUnload method

Comment: Can you try out if [gyroAvailable](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/gyroAvailable) is working and the corresponding [accelerometerAvailable](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/accelerometerAvailable)? Do you have any tools to validate hardware is running properly e.g. Xcode sample MotionGraphs or SensorMonitor?

Comment: SensorMonitor is running OK. Accelerometer and Gyro are OK. And the methods return true... this is just strange :-/

Comment: OK, [MotionGraphs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MotionGraphs/Listings/MotionGraphs_APLAccelerometerGraphViewController_m.html) does exactly the same, does it work on your device?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20952/discussion-between-kay-and-perigo)

Comment: Finally restarting my Mac helped, after restart it all just worked! :) Thanks Kay for sticking around and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally restarting my Mac helped, after restart it all just worked! :)
Thanks Kay for sticking around and help :)

Answer (score 1):

Reset your IPad. I have had this happen to me before on an ipad 2 and an ipad 3. The device just refuses to give attitude to me. I'm guessing it is because the internal gyro gets out of whack and needs to be reset.

Comment: I did that. Reset and reboot, but it's the same :-/ I'd rather try everything than Restoring the factory defaults...